# Array Implementation of Queue: Strange Output

Tags: c++, queue

I am learning about queues and I wrote the following program which implements the queue as a linear array (NOT a circular one).

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class queue {
    int front, max_queue, rear, count = 0;
    int *items;
public:
    queue(int);
    ~queue();
    void enqueue(int);
    void dequeue();
    bool isEmpty();
    int size();
    void display();
};

queue::~queue() {
    delete []items;
}

queue::queue(int max) {
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
    max_queue = max;

    items = new int[max_queue];
}

void queue::enqueue(int n) {
    if (count == max_queue)
        cout << "queue is full, no enqueue possible";
    else {
        items[++rear] = n;
        count++;
    }
}

void queue::dequeue() {
    if (count == 0)
        cout << "no dequeue possible, queue already empty";
    else {
        front--;
        count--;
    }
}

bool queue::isEmpty() {
    return ((count == 0) ? 1 : 0);
}

int queue::size() {
    return count;
}

void queue::display() {
    if (count == 0)
        cout << "nothing to display";
    else {
        for (int i = front; i <= rear;)
            cout << items[i++] << endl;
    }

}

int main() {

    queue *qe = new queue(10);

    qe->enqueue(1);
    qe->enqueue(2);
    qe->enqueue(3);
    qe->enqueue(4);
    qe->display();


    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
49
1
2
3
4

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Why is there a 49 in my output.? Is it a garbage value? Does not using a circular array implementation,a probable cause? 
I have no idea. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting the display loop i with `front` which is -1.  You're pointing to a spot before your queue.

Comment: But wont front be -1 only when the queue is empty? If count!=0 then shouldn't front be equal to 0 or any higher value?

Comment: your `enqueue` function isn't updating front though

Answer (score 1):

If a queue is empty and you enqueue an element `x`, then `x` becomes both the front and the rear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `display` function:

```
for (int i = front; i <= rear;)
    cout << items[i++] << endl;
```

You're setting `i=front`, but you've previously set `front=-1`. Thus, you're attempting to access `items[-1]`. You can either set `i=front+1`:

```
for (int i = front + 1; i <= rear;)
    cout << items[i++] << endl;
```

or continue until `i<rear` and use `++i` instead of `i++`:

```
for (int i = front; i < rear;)
    cout << items[++i] << endl;
```